# Ionic Capacitor 5 app bundle target API level error in Play console

Tags: android, capacitor, ionic5

I'm trying to submit an app update and getting the following error message: "Your app currently targets API level 26 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31.", however I'm targeting 33 in variables.gradle:

```
minSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
androidxActivityVersion = '1.7.0'
androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.6.1'
androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
androidxCoreVersion = '1.10.0'
androidxFragmentVersion = '1.5.6'
junitVersion = '4.13.2'
androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.5'
androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.5.1'
cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
androidxMaterialVersion = '1.8.0'
androidxBrowserVersion = '1.5.0'
androidxExifInterfaceVersion = '1.3.6'
firebaseMessagingVersion = '23.1.2'
playServicesLocationVersion = '21.0.1'
// capacitor-background-geolocation variables
googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = '21.0.1'
coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.0'
androidxWebkitVersion = '1.6.1'
okHttpVersion = "4.9.1"
localBroadcastManagerVersion = "1.0.0"
```

build.gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Project background_geolocation = project(':transistorsoft-capacitor-background-geolocation')
apply from: "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/app.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.XXX"
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.XXX'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 24
        versionName '3.3.3'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // [background-geolocation] Proguard-rules
            proguardFiles "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

There are no errors when changing minSdkVersion to 31, but this limits the availability of this update to newer devices only.

Where is the problem, how can I extend the support to older devices?

Comment: how does your app/build.gradle looks like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: build.gradle added to question

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in your app. You can't submit apps that target older versions of Android older than a year ago. That's to do with the Android App store.
This is by design and nothing that you can change that will solve it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm already targeting the required version, see code above (targetSdkVersion = 33) but Google says I'm targeting 31 in Google Play Console ("Target SDK 31"). Why?

Comment: The way I understand it is that we need to add the min sdk version to be 31?

Comment: The problem was solved after I hardcoded targetSdkVersion in build.gradle: "targetSdkVersion 33" instead of "targetSdk targetSdkVersion" (minSdkVersion 26), so I guess a bug?